# Type narrowing with conditional list of keys

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
type AlphaNumeric = string | number | null | boolean | undefined;

type AlphaNumericKeys<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]: key extends string ? (T[key] extends AlphaNumeric ? key : never) : never;
}[keyof T];
```

This works perfectly fine, of a generic object T it returns all the keys of T whose associated value is what I call AlphaNumeric (Im using this for sorting an array based on some keys).

For example, the Alpha numeric keys of a person are as follows:

```
type Person = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    friends: Person[];
    doSomething: Function;
}
type PersonAlphaNumericKeys = AlphaNumericKeys<Person> // "name" | "age"
```

This works perfect right now, the only problem is when I use those keys on T.

```
type AlphaNumericValuesOfPerson = Person[AlphaNumericKeys<Person>] // string | number
```

This kind of makes sense at a glance, but when I use a generic it breaks.

```
type SomeValues<T> = T[AlphaNumericKeys<T>] // T[AlphaNumericKeys<T>], not AlphaNumeric like I would expect.
```

How can I get T[AlphaNumericKeys] to be the same type as (or at least assignable to) AlphaNumeric? If I have a function that takes AlphaNumeric I want to be able to pass T[AlphaNumericKeys] to it.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly `SomeValues<T>` can be narrower than `AlphaNumeric`, so you wouldn't want it to evaluate to `AlphaNumeric` directly:

```
type S = SomeValues<{ a: 1, b: "foo", c: false, d: Date }>;
// type S = false | 1 | "foo" // a proper subtype of AlphaNumeric
```

But you are not happy that the generic `SomeValues<T>` is not seen as extending `AlphaNumeric` when `T` has not yet been specified:

```
function oops<T>(x: SomeValues<T>) {
    const y: AlphaNumeric = x; // error!
    // Type 'SomeValues<T>' is not assignable to type 'AlphaNumeric'.
}
```

This is just a design limitation of TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30728](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728) for details. The core of `SomeValues` is the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) of the form `(T[K] extends AlphaNumeric ? ...)`.  When the compiler sees that a conditional type depends on an as-yet-unspecified type parameter like `T` is, it often just *defers* evaluating that type... and when this happens the compiler cannot really verify that anything specific is assignable to it.  It just cannot perform the higher-order reasoning necessary to make the connection between `SomeValues<T>` as `AlphaNumeric`.

---

In your case, if you'd like to work around it and *tell* the compiler that `SomeValues<T>` will always be assignable to `AlphaNumeric`, you could do so by modifying its definition:

```
type SomeValues<T> = Extract<T[AlphaNumericKeys<T>], AlphaNumeric>
```

This is using [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to filter `T[AlphaNumericKeys<T>]` to only include those union members assignable to `AlphaNumeric`.  This will be a no-op for any specific value of `T`:

```
type S = SomeValues<{ a: 1, b: "foo", c: false, d: Date }>;
// type S = false | 1 | "foo" // still the same
```

but the compiler will accept that `Extract<X, Y>` is assignable to `Y` no matter what `X` is, thus solving the problem with assignability:

```
function okay<T>(x: SomeValues<T>) {
    const y: AlphaNumeric = x; // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNmAFgQwHIFcC2EBOBLAYygF4oBnYfAOwHMoAfKKrAI1wafTjg5YHs+cCMiod0VACYQAZnioQJAbgBQy0JFgIUGbPgIBpCCDIAeACoA+ElADeyqA6gBtANZGocqG5B9pUMwC6AFxe7hAAHsAQkmTklHJ0APxQABRmrkYBUBFRMZpIaFi4hFDJ3lAh8gBuuACUFUwQNTgqAL4ZPn6BKmrg0AAKuGR8oqR2jkzI2CEU1DQqE8g0EJWsuAuO0vjREmQhgzjDVE4BGw4SfADKfNjAiAkhAGLiBMB4I229GgdH8AU6xQMRlipD+2iKekMxhMPxGVgA9PCoAAiKhTCDIjjIpYY1RfaBgwq6QgANWQcHQEDIAHlpLDRlB6U5CQDIcCYUM4VlEXE5hxmJg2Dg8epoNdsGSKVTzFZSOkWRDCFDTJYAqpRVBLtZxRBJZTTDYoMgQgBGAA0UBYIWR0gEyItBBC0nJZAgFokIQAIsgolBWhYVDyNVrSM64K6OCasba+Mi8dIXm8RlABGAVRYUuEQjq9dLLPVxo4CCMKFAQCEFcSiKRwoooDzcDg+DgAIT2Rw8sx9KAAchz5P1Mp7HliVD4wCNZDIeBoaJYQigwD4i+7PcrgJ7ADplK1VGjsGQwMgCNBHnhwrZVBNgzddQO87KoABRSI4Y-AczMrREwHKmUBC11z0Cwr0cYNtVvXMDSNU0LStFEY3tKBHSgMNXXdL0fWgf0znrJFwNDF1oEYKNGBtO1QIcBMqFed5RD4FxkBAGVM2zSD73TAt2wmBxiyoUty3ycEq2sWs8JTRiQG4v08R3IA)

Comment: Perfect, this is more or less what I was hoping for, I guess I've got some reading to do on the more advanced utility types. Thanks!